# Find a counterexample to topology

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

The following conjecture is rather attractive: if $\mathbb{D}$ is a descompostition of $X$ into homeomorphic sets, say all homemorphic to $Y$, then $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}$ x $Y$.

I tried to prove it but I suppose that is false, so could you help me to find a counterexample or prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\mathbb{D}$ is a decomposition of $X$ into homeomorphic sets"?

Comment: A descompostition $\mathbb{D}$ of $X$ is a collection of disjoint subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$ . And homeomorphic sets, exists a $f$ function from $A$ to $B$ such that $f$ is one-one, onto and continuous and $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.

Comment: Ok, then how about: any topological space can be decomposed as the disjoint unions of its points, but it is not a discrete topological space in general (assuming that when you say $\mathbb{D}\times Y$ you mean to put the discrete topology on $\mathbb{D}$).

Comment: Presumably the intention is to put the quotient topology on $\mathbb D$? Especially given the tag "quotient-spaces".

Answer (score 2):

$$\Bbb R = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb Z} [n,n+1)$$ is a decomposition of $\Bbb R$ in sets homeomorphic to $[0,1)$, indexed by $\Bbb Z$, but $\Bbb Z \times [0,1)$ is disconnected and not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. If $\Bbb Z$ (as a set of represntatives for $\Bbb D$ gets the quotient topology, then it has the indiscrete topology (!) and $\Bbb D \times [0,1)$ is not $T_0$ while $\Bbb R$ is.

If all parts of the decomposition are open (and thus clopen), then we do have such a theorem, provided $\Bbb D$ gets the discrete topology. In the above example, had we given $\Bbb R$ the Sorgenfrey topology it *would* have worked, but not in the usual topology..

Answer (score 1):

A good counterexample is the [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle). One can describe it as the quotient space $K$ of the cylinder $S^1 \times [0,1]$ modulo the equivalence relation generated by $(p,1) \sim (-p,0)$, $p \in S^1$. For each $t \in [0,1]$ the quotient map  $S^1 \times [0,1] \mapsto K$ restricts to an embedding of $S^1 \times \{t\}$ into $K$, and the images give a decomposition $\mathbb D$ of $K$ into subspaces homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$. Also, the quotient topology on $\mathbb D$ makes $\mathbb D$ itself into a circle. Thus $\mathbb D \times S^1$ is homeomorphic to the torus $S^1 \times S^1$.

However, it is well know that the Klein bottle and the torus are not homeomorphic; for example, their fundamental groups are not isomorphic.

Another counterexample, closely related to the Klein bottle but perhaps even easier, is the [Möbius strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip). It has a decomposition into subsets homeomorphic to the closed interval $[0,1]$, and the quotient space $\mathbb D$ is homeomorphic to the circle.

But $\mathbb D \times [0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times [0,1]$ which is a 2-dimensional manifold-with-boundary whose boundary is disconnected, whereas the Möbius strip has connected boundary. Since any homeomorphism between two manifolds-with-boundary restricts to a homeomorphism between the boundaries, it follows that the Möbius strip is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb D \times [0,1]$.